# Pandas Datetime Index groupby century

Tags: python, pandas

```
df.groupby(df.index.year)....
```

I can groupby year using the above.  How do I group by century ?  Is it possible ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: try `df.index.year // 100`

Comment: @PaulH.  Thanks it's worked.  I didn't know you can do that in the groupby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, you can divide the year by 100 to get the century:

```
df.groupby(df.index.year // 100)
```